# SharePoint 2010 InfoPath Library Gantt Chart View MISSING Zoom In/Zoom Out Feature

Tags: list, infopath, view, library, gantt-view

How do I get the Zoom In/Zoom Out function back into the Library tab as it is in the List tab for Gantt Chart Views?  Why would is the Zoom function missing from the Library tab?

I set up a Gantt view for a InfoPath Forms Library using the document name, start date and end date; and it doesn't provide the Zoom In/Zoom Out function found in SharePoint Lists tab.  What Gives?  Can I add zoom function back into the library tab without code? Can I add it back in with code?  All I need is the same zoom function found in an OOTB SharePoint 2010 List.

As a side note - I have name, start date, and end date fields promoted to the Library from the infopath form; the InfoPath Forms Library Gantt Chart looks/feels/operates identically to a LIST Gantt Chart, just without the Zoom function (so far as I can tell).

I have SPD 2010 - so if there is SPD solution I at least have the tool to try and fix it.  But I tried editing the Gantt View and SPD will not allow me to edit the Gantt view like it will other views.